# ORACLE SQL: problema al transformar a XML un NUMBER que empieza por cero

Tags: sql, oracle, xml, numberformat

Tengo un Procedimiento almacenado en Oracle que genera un XML a partir de unos datos SQL. Me encuentro que para aquellos campos de tipo NUMBER, si comienzan por 0, en el XML de salida, ese 0 no se muestra, y sólo se muestran los decimales.
Ejemplo: si el valor es **0.82**, se muestra como:
`< importe > .82 < /importe >`

Ya he visto que esto se resolvería haciendo un `to_Char(0.82, '9990.00')` pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma más general que pueda usar dentro del PL, para poder transformar todos los campos de este tipo al generar el XML (para no tener que ir de uno en uno pues son muchísimos campos a revisar), y querría algo más genérico, para que si el día de mañana se añade un nuevo campo, no haya que tocar el PL para realizar la conversión.

¿Hay alguna opción con XMLType? Estoy usando sys_xmlgen para generarlo.

Por si sirve de ayuda, el xml de salida se valida contra un xsd en el que todos los campos numéricos son de un nuevo tipo definido:

```
<xs:simpleType name="_tipo_num2dec">
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
    <xs:pattern value="-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?">
    </xs:pattern>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si el xsd ignora la regla general: "Los ceros a la izquierda no valen" estás condenado a usar una función. Al parecer dicha regla se la tomaron muy en serio los ingenieros de Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Checa si la columna es numérica y le aplicas la conversión a char con la respectiva máscara de formato

```
IF (VALIDATE_CONVERSION(columna AS NUMBER) = 1) THEN
     TO_CHAR(columna, '9990.00')
END IF;
```

Comment: Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Finalmente tengo q hacer uso de to_char en cada referencia a dichos campos dentro del PL, pues los campos se transforman a XML a partir de objetos TYPE que tenían definido esos campos como NUMBER(15,2). He tenido que cambiarlos a VARCHAR2, y hacer la transformación al instanciar los objetos.